# How to write a custom sorting method for ngx-datatable column in Angular6?

Tags: angular, sorting, datatable, angular6, ngx-datatable

I have defined a ngx-datatable in my Angular6 project as follows and I need to sort the countries in below order in the table.

*Code-*

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows" [limit]="20" [rowHeight]="35" [headerHeight]="35" [footerHeight]="35" [scrollbarV]="true"
[columnMode]="'force'" class="material">
<ngx-datatable-column prop="name" name="name">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
        {{value}}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
<ngx-datatable-column prop="country" name="country">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
        {{value}}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

```
Order of the rows should be -  England > America > Russia
```

I can order columns Alphabetically as follows.

```
[sorts]="[{prop: 'country'}"
```

But I need to sort them as in above order. Rows are in this order. **(England > America > Russia)**.

Please help me with the sorting or using a custom comparator in ngx-databale. Thanks

Sample code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-column-reordering)

Comment: What is this sorting called? There is nothing seems related to sorting here. It's not called sorting, it is how you want to display your data. You need to make custom logic or whatever for this.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Sorting columns in above order rather than in alphabetical order. If it is a column with numbers, it is easy to sort. But I need to sort it from specific values.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya yes..sorting means, displaying rows in above order.

Comment: can you try creating a demo on stackblitz

Comment: @ParindaRajapaksha Yes that's I wanted to tell. Sorting can be either Ascending or Descending order. But in your case it is related to a way of showing the data. So in this case change data position in the .ts file.

Comment: @Allabakash code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-column-reordering

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-column-reordering

Comment: is it always only countries with England > America > Russia order ?

Comment: @Allabakash exactly. It is fixed. Only those 3 countries

Comment: @Allabakash Thanks.. Answer is correct. What if we need to sort by 'name' as well in the same time? First the country order, then sort by name. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: first sort it with name using custom sort function same as county , instead of country , check for name, once it is sorted, then again call another sort function with country. You can generalize the sort function with an option to pass property name to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom comparator function like below

```
  order = ['England', 'America', 'Russia'];

this.rows.sort((propA, propB) => {
       let indexA = this.order.indexOf(propA.country);
       let indexB = this.order.indexOf(propB.country);

       if (indexA > indexB) {

          return 1;
        } else if (indexA < indexB) {

          return -1;
        }

      return 0;
    });
```

here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-column-reordering-bl4kdh
Hope this helps

Comment: This is only work in initialize time. After each click on header the data will sort by default!